# Choosing parcels listed from Excel sheet in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins, select-by-attribute, parcel

I was sent an Excel sheet by a different department with all the parcel numbers they want to be mapped. They are all over the county.

What is the best way to select the parcels that were given to me in an Excel sheet in my tax parcel layer in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot to show what you have? It's a bit difficult to understand the question like this.

Comment: Done, basically have a long list of a few thousand parcels in an excel sheet that I want to map.  how do i select the parcels in the excel sheet that are in my parcel layer without going throuhg 1 by 1 lol

Comment: So and you also have a vector layer with parcel polygons? Then the best way is a table join (https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#joins-properties) - under condition that both layers have a common field (`Parcel#`?)

Comment: After the join, which @Babel proposed, you can [filter](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#query-builder) your data (e.g. #your excels' parcel-field# IS NOT NULL) to show only the parcels in your excel.